# Move to a particular tab of bottom navigation from an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am working on a project in which I used Bottom Navigation Bar. On Nav Bar, I used 4 menu items(Profile, Home, Reservation, Logout), for them I used fragment.
Moving to Home, a list of restaurant will be appear. When the user tap on any restaurant from the list, an activity( name ReservationInfo ) will be opened. There are 3 edit text fields and a button in ReservationInfo activity. When the user click on the button it will move to the fragment(Reservation) which is placed on third position of bottom nav bar.

The question is how to move from activity to fragmentand the fragment is set to the 3rd menu item of the bottom navigation bar.

Here is the code:

**Resrvation.java**

```
package restaurantlocator.application;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Resrvation extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button reserve;
    ImageButton imageButton;
    EditText food, chooseTime, date;
    DataBaseHelper db;
//  ReservationInfo reservationInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resrvation);
        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        food = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etfood);
        chooseTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettime);
        date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edate);
        reserve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreserve);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                finish();
            }
        });

        //reservationInfo = new ReservationInfo();

        reserve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!emptyValidation()) {
                    db.AddData(new Data(food.getText().toString(),
                            chooseTime.getText().toString(),
                            date.getText().toString()));
                    AlertMessage();
                    food.setText(null);
                    chooseTime.setText(null);
                    date.setText(null);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Resrvation.this, "Empty Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            private void AlertMessage() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Resrvation.this);
                builder.setTitle("Reserved!");
                builder.setMessage("A notification will be send on your device regarding your reservation.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            //move to fragment ReservationInfo
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean emptyValidation() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(food.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(chooseTime.getText().toString())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**BottomNavigation.java**

```
package restaurantlocator.application;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class BottomNavigation extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView mMianNav;
    private FrameLayout mMainFrame;
    private HomeActivity homeActivity;
    private ReservationInfo reservationInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_navigation);
        startService(new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));

        mMainFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
        mMianNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_nav);

        homeActivity = new HomeActivity();
        reservationInfo = new ReservationInfo();
        setFragment(homeActivity);


        //Listener for handling selection events on bottom navigation items
        mMianNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.tohome:
                        setFragment(homeActivity);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.toresrvation:
                        setFragment(reservationInfo);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.tologout:
                        logout();
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }

            private void logout() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BottomNavigation.this, Registration.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue a bit more..

Comment: how to move from an activity (named Resrvation) to a fragment? that fragment name is ResrvationInfo. when the fragment is set to  the 3rd menu item of bottom navigation bar.

Comment: I am unable to elaborate the problem. :(

Comment: have to move from activity to fragment and that fragment is set to the 3rd menu item of bottom navigation bar.

Comment: I got that part, Is the Fragment in the same activity or in a different activity, I'm confused there.

Comment: fragment is a separate,

Comment: i have to move from `Resrvation` activity to `ReservationInfo` Fragment which is separate but it is set to the 3rd item of bottom navigation bar, item id is `toresrvation`.

Comment: Okay as I understand, You want to move from `Reservation` activity to `ReservationInfo` Fragment right?

Comment: yesssss........

Comment: Ahh, From the `reserve..` Click listener?

Comment: yyeesss............

Comment: Okay, I'm writing a solution now, Give me 5 minutes

Comment: okay............

Comment: Please check out the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

Follow the steps below:

**Step1:** Add the lines as shown in below `reserve` click listener

```
reserve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ....
        ....
        Intent intent = new Intent(Resrvation.this, BottomNavigation.class);
        intent.putExtra("FromReservation", "1");
        startActivity(intent);
        ....
    }
}
```

Next, **Step2:** In your write the below code in `onCreate()` of `BottomNavigation` class:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String data = i.getStringExtra("FromReservation");

if (data != null && data.contentEquals("1")) {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, new ReservationInfo());
    fragmentTransaction.commitNow();

    mMianNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.toresrvation);

}
```

Try it, If any problem, do comment below.

Comment: @AmnaMughal Okay

Comment: it works only if placing `mMianNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.toresrvation);`  above `FragmentTransaction.....`.

Comment: Yeah, However you declare it in your onCreate(), it will go :) @AmnaMughal

Comment: also using `setFragment(reservationInfo);` instead of `FragmentTransaction........`.

Comment: Oh Yeah, Sorry, I took the contents instead of the function.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just use `startActivityForResults` instead of `startActivity` when user selects a restaurant from your home fragment.

e.g :

```
startActivityForResult(yourIntent, 1000);
```

And on the reservationInfo Activity in the `onClick` function use

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

And then in your first activity override `onActivityResult()` method and set the selected fragment as reservation if request code matches

e.g:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1000) {
    mMianNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.toresrvation);
}
```

}

Comment: there is no `onClick` method  used in restaurationinfo, ther is just a list.